# LAPACKE/GNU C++: Weird bug in LAPACKE_zheevx() function

Tags: c++, g++, codeblocks, lapack, lapacke

here is a description of a weird bug I have encountered when using LAPACKE's function LAPACKE_zheevx(). Simple test code that calculates three out of four eigenvalues/vectors (the example from the Intel's website) works well and gives correct output. However, if I introduce declaration of any string in the source code (e.g. std::string OutputFIlename;), the compilation goes well but at execution I get segmentation error SIGSEGV !!!

First, I will list the code that works:

```
//===========================
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>  
#include <cassert>  

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex>
#include <math.h>

#include "Headers_LAPACKE\lapacke.h"
#include "Headers_LAPACKE\lapacke_config.h"
#include "Headers_LAPACKE\lapacke_mangling.h"
#include "Headers_LAPACKE\lapacke_utils.h"

void print_matrix( char* desc, lapack_int m, lapack_int n, lapack_complex_double* a, lapack_int lda );

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Start..." << std::endl;
    //std::string fn_VALS; 

    // --------------- LAPACKE --- define variables ----------------------------------------------------------------
    //

    // Define arguments for LAPACKE_zheevx() routine:
    int matrix_layout;  // = LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR or LAPACK_COL_MAJOR

    char jobz;          // It is ="V" to calculate EigenVECTORS and
                        // ="N" if you don't do it.

    char range;         // ="A" for ALL values (don't want this),
                        // ="V" for values in in the half-open interval (vl,vu],
                        // ="I" for EigenVALUES indexed from il through iu (this is what you want).

    char uplo;          // ="U" for Upper Triangle of the matrix, or
                        // ="L" for the Lower triangle of the matrix.

    lapack_int n;       // the order of matrix "a" to be diagonalized.

    lapack_complex_double* a;   // complex array of dimension (lda,n).
                                // On entry it is Hermitian matrix "a".
                                // uplo="U" means the leading n-by-n upper triangular part of "a" contain the upper triangular part of the Hermitial matrix to be diagonalized.
                                // uplo="L" means equivalent for the lower triangular part.
                                // On exit, this content is destroyed.

    lapack_int lda;     // leading dimension of "a": lda >= max(1,n).

    double    vl;         // taken into account only if range="V": vl<vu. Not referenced if range="I" or range="A".
    double    vu;         // taken into account only if range="V": vl<vu. Not referenced if range="I" or range="A".

    lapack_int il;      // taken into account only if range="I": il<iu. Indices in ascending order of SMALLEST EigenVALUE to be returned. Not referenced if range="v" or range="A".
    lapack_int iu;      // taken into account only if range="I": il<iu. Indices in ascending order of LARGEST EigenVALUE to be returned.  Not referenced if range="v" or range="A".

    double    abstol;     // The absolute error tolerance for EigenVALUES. If abstop =<0, then EPS*|T| is used. If you get info>0 (some eigenvalues did not converge) then try abstol=2*DLAMCH('S').
    lapack_int* m;      // total number of EigenVALUES found: 0 =< m =< n, If range="A" then m=n, if range="I" then m = iu-il+1.
    double* w;          // double precision array of dimension n. On normal exit, the first m elements contain the selected EigenVALUES in ASCENDING ORDER.
    lapack_complex_double* z; // double precision array of dimension (ldz, max(1,m)). If jobz="V" and info=0, the first m-columns of z contain normalized EigenVECTORS of a, corresponding to the selected EigenVALUES, with i-th column of z contains the Eigenvectro corresponding to w(i) eigenvalue.
    lapack_int ldz;     // leading dimension of array z. ldz>=1 and if jobz="V" then ldz >= max(1,n).

        // following are  used only with LAPACKE_zheevx_work() routine:.
        //lapack_complex_double* work;    // array of dimension max(1,lwork).
        //lapack_int lwork;               // lwork=-1 means workspace query. Othewise it has to be length of the array work: lwork=2*n for n>1, and lwork >=1 for N=<1.
        //double* rwork;                  // array dimension is 7*n;
        //lapack_int* iwork;              // array dimension is 5*n;

    lapack_int* ifail;  // jobz="V" and info=0: first m elemens of ifail are zero. jobz="V" and info>0: ifail contain indices of the eigenvectors that failed to converge.
    lapack_int info;    //info=0 means successful exit. info>0 means eigenvectors failed to converge, their indices are in ifail. info<0, info=-i means i-th argument had an illegal value.
    //
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    matrix_layout = LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR;
    jobz = 'V'; vl = 0.0; vu =100.0;
    il = 1; iu=4; // are ignored now.
    range = 'V';
    uplo ='U';
    n = 4;
    lda = n;
    ldz = n;

    z = new lapack_complex_double [ldz*n];
    w = new double [n];
    a = new lapack_complex_double [lda*n];
    a[0] =lapack_complex_double{6.51,0.0}; a[1] =lapack_make_complex_double(-5.92, 9.53); a[2]=lapack_complex_double{-2.46,2.91}; a[3]=lapack_complex_double{8.84,3.21};
    a[4] =lapack_complex_double{0.0,0.0};  a[5] =lapack_make_complex_double(-1.73,0.0);   a[6]=lapack_complex_double{6.5,2.09};    a[7]=lapack_complex_double{1.32, 8.81};
    a[8] =lapack_complex_double{0.0,0.0};  a[9] =lapack_make_complex_double(0.0,0.0);     a[10]=lapack_complex_double{6.90,0.0};   a[11]=lapack_complex_double{-0.59,2.47};
    a[12]=lapack_complex_double{0.0,0.0};  a[13]=lapack_make_complex_double(0.0,0.0);     a[14]=lapack_complex_double{0.0,0.0};    a[15]=lapack_complex_double{-2.85,0.0};

    ifail = new lapack_int [n];
    abstol = -1;  // set default tolerance for calcuation of EigVals in the assigned interval.

    print_matrix( "Entry Matrix A:", n, n, a, lda );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    info = LAPACKE_zheevx(matrix_layout, jobz, range, uplo, n, a, lda,  vl,  vu,  il, iu,  abstol, m, w, z, ldz, ifail);

    if (info>0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: ZHEEVX failed to compute eigenvalues/vectors.";
        exit(1);
    }
    std::cout << "info = " << info << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Number of eigvals found: " << *m << std::endl;
    for (int i_e =0; i_e<*m; i_e++)
    {
         std::cout << "Eigval. " << i_e << " is " << w[i_e] << std::endl;
    }

    print_matrix( "Selected EigVECTORS (column-wise):", n, n, z, ldz );
    std::cout << std::endl;


    std::cout << "Done :-) !!!" <<std::endl;

    return 0;
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////* Auxiliary routine: printing a matrix */
void print_matrix( char* desc, lapack_int m, lapack_int n, lapack_complex_double* a, lapack_int lda )
{
        lapack_int i, j;
        printf( "\n %s\n", desc );
        for( i = 0; i < m; i++ )
        {
            for( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
            {
                printf( " (%6.2f,%6.2f)", lapack_complex_double_real(a[i*lda+j]), lapack_complex_double_imag(a[i*lda+j]) );
            }
            printf( "\n" );
        }
}
//=======================================
```

Now, if in main() one removes the comment symbol (//) on line 2: //std::string fn_VALS; this will become std::string fn_VALS; With this the source will compile, but it fails at the runtime with segmentation error SIGSEGV.

More info:

I am using Windows 7 Pro and Code::Blocks, the LAPACKE headers and dll's were downloaded on 6/15/2016. 
From the console: Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
From the Call Stack window in Code::Blocks

.......... main() calls LAPACKE_zheevx() [lapacke.dll]

.......... LAPACKE_zheevx() calls LAPACKE_zheevx_work() [lapacke.dll]

.......... LAPACKE_zheevx_work() calls zheevx_() [lapack.dll]

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to compile the program you prodived by typing:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -llapacke -llapack -lblas -lm -Wall
```

The flag `-Wall` enables all warnings. One of the warnings is interesting:

> warning: ‘m’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

The pointer `lapack_int* m;` is not initialized as `LAPACKE_zheevx(..., m, ...);` is called. Hence, it can point to anywhere in the memory. The pointer `m` is expected to host an output parameter of the function, and it is likely that `LAPACKE_zheevx()` or a subsequent function dereferences the pointer `m`. It leads to undefined behavior: depending on where `m` points to, it can remain unnoticed or it can trigger a segmentation fault.

Could you try `lapack_int* m[1];` instead of `lapack_int* m;`?

[This example from intel](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/lapacke_zheevx_row.c.htm) does not feature the same problem as `m` is decleared as an `MKL_INT` and passed by argument to the function (`&m`). Is it the one you started from?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped. Here is what I have changed in the code:  just introduced line with  m = new lapack_int [1];  the variables in the call to LAPACKE_zheevx were kept as they were.

Comment: All the variables that are passed back from LAPACKE_zheevxI() as result/output were treated as pointer arrays. Only the single value of "m" was not, and now when "m" became a pointer array with one element m[0] - it worked.

Comment: I am wondering if there is a nice webpage with examples for LAPACKE high/mid level routines? I was not able to fine one. This Intel webiste (yes, I was using that example) utilizes their own MKL

Comment: Thanks once again.

Comment: **Merci beaucoup**

Comment: You're welcome! If you are happy with this answer, consider upvoting it and/or accepting it by clicking the checkmark right under the arrows. There are some examples in the folder [LAPACKE/example](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dir_d5af77e92c6b4a03536ccb1e9af4ef49.html) DGELS and DGESV.  But i am afraid that the only website featuring examples of use of LAPACKE here and there is Stackoverflow!

Comment: The rule of thumb for functions of LAPACKE is that you have to care about memory allocation for both input parameters and output parameters passed by argument. Fortunately the prototypes of the functions of LAPACKE are very close to those of the correponding functions in LAPACK. The documentation of LAPACK is very helpful to define the sizes of the arrays. You can directly take a look at the source code of the function and read the comments!